# SQL and Active Directory groups, Schema permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-permissions

I have the following problem, we assign perms in SQL 2014 using ad groups. we have the following

**l_sql-db-demodb-dbo:**  this is a local group where we assign the actual permission (dbowner against 'demodb')

**g_sql-db-demodb-dbo:**       global group that is a member of the above

**user:**    user is added to global group giving permissions for dbo to demodb.

This all works fine... mostly. User tries to run SQL profiler 2014 and run a trace and output trace to demodb. User can select the database, cannot select a schema.

If I assign the same exact permission set against the user account itself, it works as expected. for some reason the groups (or the nesting of groups) are killing this ability.

Note that this is SQL 2014 SP1. SP2 has not been approved for rollout, so I'm not sure if this is a bug..